# does javascript have a main method? I want to instantiate variables and run them at a specific time. Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I would like to take a user input, and update this input every time this input is changed. When this happens, the "main" method should run a block of code and reset the userChange and updateCalc back to false...**

```
    //For Example
    updateCalc=false;
    userChange= false;


    $(function(){

      $("#inputUsers").change(function(){  // user input that can be called at anytime
    userChange = true;
    inputUsers = $(this).val();
    updateCalc = true;
    });

    if(updateCalc == true){  //"main" method that is called whenever updatecalc is true

    alert(1);
updateCalc = false;
userChange = false;
    }




    });
```

Comment: Your code looks rather silly to me. Why are you setting updateCalc and userChange to true when you just change it back to false? If you want to execute a function on change, just call it inside the event handler

Comment: I see what you mean. At first I thought I would need them as booleans. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking method wrong. You can do but with different way. I hope it helps

```
updateCalc=false;
userChange= false;

checker_func = function() {
  $("#inputUsers").change(function(){  // user input that can be called at anytime
     userChange = true;
     inputUsers = $(this).val();
     updateCalc = true;
  });

  if(updateCalc == true){ 
    alert(1);
    updateCalc = false;
    userChange = false;
  }
}

setInterval("checker_func();",1000); // checks your codes every 1000 milisecond
```